# Android - не могу применить шрифт

Tags: android-textview, android, шрифты, java

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь применить шрифт к `TextView` вот этим кодом:

```
static TextView title;
...
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/aa-bebasneue.ttf");
title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.theme_neongreen_title);
title.setTypeface(tf);
```

При запуске программы она крашится, а в логах указывается ошибка `Native typeface cannot be made`. Пробовал самые разные шрифты, даже перемещал их через разные проводники, но всё равно пишет эту ошибку. Как решить эту проблему?

**Закрываю вопрос, так как решил проблему сам: в манифесте выставил минимальный API 10 вместо 7.**

Comment: Неужели все программисты уснули?)

Comment: А если просто поместить шрифт в Assets без папки fonts? Тогда шрифт применяется?

Comment: @Lucky_spirit нет, всё равно выводит ошибку

Answer (score 1):

Причины у таковой ошибки может быть две:

1. Неверно указан путь к файлу и/или его имя — наиболее частая ошибка, поскольку многие забывают, что `Font.ttf` и `font.ttf` — два разных файла.
2. Повреждённый или невалидный файл шрифта, что менее вероятно.

Шрифт *AA Bebas Neue* распространяется с именем *ttf*-файла *AA-BebasNeue.ttf*, а стало быть, если вы его не переименовывали сами, то и путь к нему в коде указан неверно, а должно быть что-то типа:

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/AA-BebasNeue.ttf");
```

Comment: @falstaf я знаю, что имя файла чувствительно к регистру, но оно указано правильно. Сейчас пробовал извлечь шрифт, сохраняя его оригинальное имя, всё равно выкидывает. Пробовал даже обновлять android-support-library в v4 на v7 и собирать проект через другую IDE. Так же выкижывает.

Answer (score 1):

Решение от автора:

**в манифесте выставил минимальный API 10 вместо 7.**